# Windows 7 Consistency Check at Startup Hangs

Tags: windows-7, boot

Each time I start my computer, it wants to do a consistency check.  Whether I try to cancel it or not, it counts down from 9 to 1, but hangs at 1.... Nothing happens.  What do I do now?

Comment: Test the hard drive with the manufacturer's software. Seagate, Western Digital and others each have tools that can be launched in a pre-boot environment, or DOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, unplugging all peripherals fixed it( mouse headphones etc) no idea why that fixed it but it worked.